# Tech tree for buildings and units

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

I am playing Medieval 2:Total War,  vanilla without any mods. Is there some way to access an in game tech tree,  that will show,  which buildings are required for producing a particular unit type. For eg: to see what buildings are required to be built in a settlement, to enable that settlement to start building longbow men.

Cheers.,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. If you have by any chance misclicked and opened the Settlement Tab, then you're on the right place.

There is a page where you can view what buildings are maintained if you switch from Castle -> City type settlements and vice-versa. In that tab you can right click on the icons to open the info page regarding different types of buildings, and each building's ability to create. As an example, if you right click on 'Mustering Hall', it will state that you're able to create peasants there.

In game, there is no other way to do this (unless you already have the building, in which case you just go to the building tab and right click on it to see what you can build. Or, in the construction page, the same with buildings you can construct). However, you can't select a unit and see which buildings are required to create it, which is a pity.

Comment: If someone remembers the right key shortcut for it, I would immensely appreciate. It's the button with a brown building and a magnifying glass under the Construction Tab. I cannot check it for myself right now. Due credits to whoever remembers the shortcut or posts a screenshot